# referencing ant script location from within ant file

Tags: java, ant

I have a utility build script that gets called from a variety of project-specific build scripts on a build server.  Everything works fine, until the relative directory structure changes.  That is:

```
trunk/
    utilities/
        imported.xml
        some_resource_file
    projectName/
        importing.xml
```

works just fine, but sometimes we need:

```
trunk/
    importing.xml
    utilities/
        imported.xml
        some_resource_file
    projectName/
```

The problem is that `imported.xml` needs `some_resource_file` and currently gets to it by referring to `../utilities/some_resource_file`.  This obviously works in the first case because the working directory is a sibling of `utilities`.

Is there a simple way for `imported.xml` to know what directory it's in, something equivalent to `dirname $0` in bash?  Or do I have to do I have to somehow inject this from the importing script?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure that imported.xml defines project with `name` attribute.  Then you can use that name for an absolute path to the ant file through `ant.file.name` property.

I have capitalized IMPORTED, so you can easily see it in the code.

```
<project
  name="IMPORTED"
>
  <dirname
    property="IMPORTED.basedir"
    file="${ant.file.IMPORTED}"
  />
  <property name="myresource"
    location="${IMPORTED.basedir}/some_resource_file"
  />
</project>
```

Comment: That works great.  I found the answer in the manual, but only copied the link here.  Maybe this will help others who don't find it easy to navigate the ant manual.

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html

Check under *resolving files against the imported file*.