# Change baseDir attribute while using import tag

Tags: ant

Let me first provide the background of the problem I'm facing.

I have a directory structure as below.

c:\myDirectory
c:\myDirectory\Project1
c:\myDirectory\Scripts

Under the **c:\myDirectory\Scripts** there is a script that download  the source code (from svn) and creates the **c:\myDirectory\Project1** directory.

I have another ant scripts ( **c:\myDirectory\Scripts**compile-source.xml** ) that compiles the Project1 
from an ant script build.xml that is downloaded to **c:\myDirectory\Project1**

Snippet for c:\myDirectory\Scripts\compile-source.xml

```
<project name="compile" default="buildAll" basedir=".">
    <property file=".\build.properties">
    </property>
    .......
    <import file="${project.home.path}/${project.name}/build.xml"/>
     <target name="buildAll">
      <antcall target="jar-pack"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Snippet for c:\myDirectory\Project1\build.xml.

```
<project name="CommonFeatures" default="jar-pack" basedir=".">
        <description>
            A build file for the Common Features project
        </description>
        ....
    </project>
```

Note that the basedir for the project is set as "." for both the above ant scripts.

When I execute the script **c:\myDirectory\Scripts\compile-source.xml** from the **c:\myDirectory\Scripts** directory the target **"jar-pack"** present in the **c:\myDirectory\Project1\build.xml** gets executed.

However,  the problem is that basedir attribude in  build.xml ( **basedir="."** ) is the current working directory and in this case its **c:\myDirectory\Scripts**. Hence the script build.xml errors out since the basedir for build.xml is expected to be **c:\myDirectory\Project1**. The build.xml script would have worked, if basedir="."  were set to **"c:\myDirectory\Project1"**, but unfortunately build.xml file comes from the source code that is downloaded and I'm unable to edit.

So here's my question,  Is it possible to do any of the following.

1. Override the value of the attribude  basedir="." in build.xml when the  is done in c:\myDirectory\Scripts\compile-source.xml ?
2. Is it possible to change the basedir in build.xml by any other mechanism so that the script c:\myDirectory\Project1\build.xml is executed under directory c:\myDirectory\Project1 ?
3. Any other way to resolve this issue?

Any help from Ant experts to overcome this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Read http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can update **basedir** using **subant** task. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745829/how-to-specify-base-dir-then-we-run-ant-like-ant-f-somedir-dir-build-xml/16295389#16295389)

Create the following **build.xml** file (assuming it is in **Z:/any/folder**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project">
    <target name="mytarget">
        <subant target="debug">
            <property name="basedir" value="X:/any/dir/with/project"/>
            <fileset dir="Y:/any/folder/with" includes="build.xml"/>
        </subant>
    </target>
</project>
```

The you can execute **ant mytarget** from **Z:/any/folder**

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically reference the location of your build file, which is described in [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676939/referencing-ant-script-location-from-within-ant-file). This would allow you to get and use the directory your build file resides in as a reference point.

Answer (score 0):

For your case the usage of the `subant` or `ant` tasks may be better suited, but nevertheless...

You **can (but you should know/consider the side-effects!)** extend ant with the common **[ant-contrib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/1.0b3/) task definitions** and use the **[`var` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html)** which is able to **override** properties. Make sure to use the latest version (`> 1.0b3`).

```
<!-- adjust to your path and include it somewhere at the beginning of your project file -->
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpath="lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />

<!-- works e.g. for basedir = /foo/bar to update it to /foo/bar/.. ~ /foo -->
<var name="basedir" value="${basedir}/.." />
```

update: but one has to be careful, because this **does not change `.` (current working directory)** (so `<property name="x" location="tmp" />` would be relative to `.` and not to `basedir` anymore ; update: setting `basedir` outside of ant or via `<project basedir=` also sets `.` to `basedir`!). Here is some test target proving the effect on both:

```
<target name="tst.dummy.basedir-override">
    <!-- example output:
        tst.dummy.basedir-override:
             [echo] basedir before: basedir=D:\tst,  '.'=D:\tst\.
             [echo] updating it via 'var' to '..'
             [echo] basedir now:  basedir=D:\tst/..,  '.'=D:\tst\.
    -->
    <property name="cur" location="." /> <!-- makes the relative path absolute -->
    <echo message="basedir before: basedir=${basedir},  '.'=${cur}" />

    <echo message="updating it via 'var' to '..'" />
    <var name="basedir" value="${basedir}/.." />

    <property name="cur2" location="." /> <!-- makes the relative path absolute -->
    <echo message="basedir now:  basedir=${basedir},  '.'=${cur2}" />
</target>
```