# How to specify base dir then we run ant like ant -f somedir/dir/build.xml

Tags: java, ant

How to specify base dir then we run ant like `ant -f somedir/dir/build.xml.`
Ant sets basedir relative to build.xml, if I specify

```
<project basedir="." ..>
```

I would like to have basedir pointed to place where Ant is executed.

Comment: can you copy build.xml to another directory?

Comment: yes, but I'd prefer do not copy this file

Comment: link or symlink it then?

Comment: I would like do not write additional commands in scripts. I'd like to modify build.xml

Comment: I have absolutely no idea then. sorry :)

Comment: ant is not obvious thing

Comment: you could possibly set a property on the command line with -D<property>=<value> where value is the basedir. not certain, its been years since i climbed the ant hill.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use -D to override the basedir property:

```
ant -Dbasedir=`pwd` -f path/to/build.xml
```

The use of `pwd` is a Linux-only thing, but you can always put the absolute path of the current directory there if you're on another platform.

I don't think there's a way to do this inside build.xml, short of re-executing ant with the `ant` task.

Answer (score 9):

You can try to use **subant** task:

Assuming you have two different folders

1. Your current folder **X:/your/launching/folder** where you are executing **ant** command from
2. Folder where your destination bulid.xml is: **Y:/any/folder/with/build.xml**

You can do the following:

Create **build.xml** in **X:/your/launching/folder** with the next content:

```
<target name="mytarget">
    <subant target="debug">
        <fileset dir="Y:/any/folder/with" includes="build.xml"/>
    </subant>
</target>
```

Then you can execute **ant mytarget** from **X:/your/launching/folder** folder to start building your **Y:/any/folder/with/build.xml**

**Update:**

You can override **basedir** property for subant build like this:

```
    <subant target="debug">
        <property name="basedir" value="./any/dir/with/project"/>
        <fileset dir="Y:/any/folder/with" includes="build.xml"/>
    </subant>
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution (if it makes more sense in some cases) could be to **override `basedir` via the `var` task** from the `antcontrib` extension as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25786329/1915920

Answer (score 0):

I found, that using following solution is the easiest.

```
pushd somedir/dir && ant && popd
```

Although is seems to be to easy - it works.