# ant get absolute directory of current file

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to set up one antfile ("antfile_A" located in directory A) to call another antfile ("antfile_B" located in directory B).

My problem is that all the file operations when I call antfile_B from antfile_A appear to be relative to directory A.  I could hardcode the paths in antfile_b to be relative to directory A, but then I can't really use antfile_B by itself.

I've tried setting basedir (to ".") at the top of each antfile, but the "." seems to resolve to directory A when antfile_B is called from antfile_A.

Is there any way to get the absolute directory that an antfile is located in directly?  In python, it would be something like

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

How do other people solve this problem?  (Or are you not really supposed to call one antfile from another?)  Please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676939/referencing-ant-script-location-from-within-ant-file

Comment: The attached link solves the problem.  I must have missed it; flagging my question as a potential duplicate.  Thanks, Nishant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ant.file`. This example prints absolute path of the build file:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="abspath" basedir=".">
  <target name="abspath">
    <echo message="${ant.file}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

If you try to run `ant` with `-d` (debug output) flag you'll find the properties which are set before the first target is invoked and, as a result, are usable within the build file.

This is taken from the output when the above build file is run with `-d` flag:

```
...
Setting ro project property: ant.file -> /Users/abc/xyz/build.xml
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type -> file
Setting ro project property: ant.project.name -> MyProject
Setting ro project property: ant.project.default-target -> abspath
Setting ro project property: ant.file.MyProject -> /Users/abc/xyz/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type.MyProject -> file
...
```

---

For completeness, you can obtain the path to the directory containing the build script by creating a variable as follows:

```
<dirname property="my.project.dir" file="${ant.file}"/>
```

Comment: I think you're right: the trick is to use ${ant.file}.  For completeness, if you want the directory rather than the file itself, you can run
 <dirname
    property="real_dir"
    file="${ant.file}"
  />
Or extend ant.file with the name of the project as well.  Thanks.  I'm accepting your answer.